# Animate div from right to left (react)

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, slide

I have two div´s in a container div.

When I press the left div it expands to the right using {transition: 1s} in the CSS. 
When I press the right div I want it to expand from right to left, but it expands and THEN "slides" to the right.

Any tips?
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to show us some of your code and/or a JSFiddle demo!

Comment: A JSFiddle of this would be great!
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: if you are using css animations you may want to add `forwards` at the end of your `animation` statement in your css file